# Turning image into blob in React Native (Expo) and uploading to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo

I have a camera component which I clicks a picture. I store the clicked picture using expo's FileSystem in the local cacheDirectory. Looks some thing like this:

```
onPictureSaved = async photo => {
    await FileSystem.moveAsync({
        from: photo.uri,
        to: `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}test.jpg`
    });}
```

My next step is to my next stop is converting the image in the local cacheDirectory into a blob and upload the image into S3 via the `aws-sdk`:

```
var params = {
            Bucket: "my-bucket", 
            Key: 'test.jpg',
            Body: blob
           };

           s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } // an error occurred
            else  { 
                console.log(data);
            }         // successful response

          }
```

However, any methods or modules I install in order to accomplish this tiny step in the process hasn't been working at all. I can't use `RNFS`, `react-native-fetch-blob` or any other modules that require linking thanks to the expo client. I don't want to detach expo just for one thing. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/expo/image-upload-example/issues/3#issuecomment-387263080. The latest expo release supports blobs, so then you can do something like the following:

```
uploadToS3 = async (fileUri, s3Bucket, s3Key) => {
const response = await fetch(fileUri);
const blob = await response.blob();
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: s3Bucket,
    Key: s3Key,
    Body: blob,
  };
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong');
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully uploaded image');
      resolve(data);
    }
  });
});
```

};

Hope this helps!