# how to upload images using Zendesk Upload API

Tags: react-native, zendesk-api

I'm using the function below to upload images on zendesk. Zendesk requires image to be in binary to be uploaded and getting the blob image method is working when I'm uploading on Firebase. These function gets a response 201 but when you check the image, is just a white square. I think image got corrupted during the upload.

imageUri is returned from expo-image-picker like this below:

> file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/.../ImagePicker/8543faa5-b996-46cd-9554-ce9afb61385b.jpg

```
const uploadImages = async (imageUri) => {

    try {
        const filename = getFilenameFromImagePicker(imageUri);
    
        const resImg = await fetch(imageUri);
        const blobImg = await resImg.blob();
    
        const response = await axios.post(`uploads?filename=${filename}`, {
            blobImg
        }, {
            auth: {
                username: membersEmail + '/token',
                password: ZENDESK_API_KEY
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/binary',
            }
        })
    
        return response.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        captureException(error);
        return null;
    }

}
```

What is the best way to change the image to binary so it can be uploaded to zendesk?

```
Below is the curl statement from Zendesk's documentation for uploading images

curl "https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/uploads?filename=myfile.dat&token={optional_token}" \
  -data-binary @file.dat \
  -v -u {email_address}:{password} \
  -H "Content-Type: application/binary" \
  -X POST
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning image into blob in React Native (Expo) and uploading to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974249/turning-image-into-blob-in-react-native-expo-and-uploading-to-s3-bucket)

Comment: No, because the example you gave me is doing the same thing as mine. I guess you didn't read my question or the answer you attached.

Comment: React Native don't support application/binary upload format https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360039238193-facing-issue-to-upload-attachment-in-react-native-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of testing, I was able to make it work. Posting here the answer I come up with incase someone else has the same problem.

```
async function uploadImages (imageUri) {
        // first get our hands on the local file
        const localFile = await fetch(imageUri);
    
        // then create a blob out of it (only works with RN 0.54 and above)
        const fileBlob = await localFile.blob();
    
        // then send this blob to filestack
        const serverRes = await fetch('https://www.yourAwesomeServer.com/api/send/file', { // Your POST endpoint
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': application/binary,
            },
            body: fileBlob, // This is your file object
        });
    
        const serverJsonResponse = await serverRes.json();
        return serverJsonResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my **typescript** solution and it works.
*file* is file from

```
static uploadVideo = async (file:any) => {  
    // first get our hands on the local file
    const localFile = await fetch(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    // then create a blob out of it 
    const fileBlob = await localFile.blob();
    const url = `${YOUR_URL}/v2/uploads?filename=${file?.name}`
    return await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: fileBlob,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/binary'}
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).